# Why flexbox in column and wrap is broken

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My code is

```html
<div id="parent">
   <div class="produit_sup">
      <p>Aubergine</p>
      <p>Betterave</p>
      <p>Courgette</p>
      <p>Oignon</p>
      <p>Poireau</p>
      <p>Pomme de terre</p>
      <p>Tomate</p>
   </div>
</div>

<style>
#parent{
   display: flex;
}
.produit_sup{
   max-height: 100px;
   background: #c3c3ff;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.produit_sup>p{
   width: 100px;
   text-align: left;
   margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
</style>
```

Why it's look like that
[image: My result]

And not like that
[image: What I want]

I want to save `display:flex;` of parent and I my number of `<p>` items can be changing on the time

Answer (score -1):

Try to add to .produit_sup some `flex-basis` or `width`, like `width:50%`.

```html
<div id="parent">
   <div class="produit_sup">
      <p>Aubergine</p>
      <p>Betterave</p>
      <p>Courgette</p>
      <p>Oignon</p>
      <p>Poireau</p>
      <p>Pomme de terre</p>
      <p>Tomate</p>
   </div>
</div>

<style>
#parent{
   display: flex;
}
.produit_sup{
   width: 50%;
   max-height: 100px;
   background: #c3c3ff;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.produit_sup>p{
   width: 100px;
   margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It's wrong for same reasons of @casraf because if I have 20 <p>, items will go out of `.produit_sup`. And size of a column is not fixed

Answer (score -1):

You can do one of the following:

1. Remove `flex` from your `#parent`
2. Set `#parent`'s direction to `column`
3. Set an alternate width to `#parent`, such as `100%` or `200px`.

```html
<div id="parent">
   <div class="produit_sup">
      <p>Aubergine</p>
      <p>Betterave</p>
      <p>Courgette</p>
      <p>Oignon</p>
      <p>Poireau</p>
      <p>Pomme de terre</p>
      <p>Tomate</p>
   </div>
</div>

<style>
#parent{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   width: 200px;
}
.produit_sup{
   max-height: 100px;
   background: #c3c3ff;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.produit_sup>p{
   width: 100px;
   text-align: left;
   margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It's wrong because if I have 20 `<p>`, items will go out of `.produit_sup`